# How to delete networkpolicies using kubectl?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubectl

I've followed a Kubernetes tutorial similar to:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/ which created some basic networkpolicies as follows:

```
root@server:~# kubectl get netpol -n policy-demo
NAME           POD-SELECTOR   AGE
access-nginx   run=nginx      49m
default-deny   <none>         50m
```

I saw that I can delete the entire namespace (pods included) using a command like "kubectl delete ns policy-demo", but I can't see what command I need to use if I just want to delete a single policy (or edit it even).

How would I use kubectl to delete just the "access-nginx" policy above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work. A similar command works at my end.

```
kubectl -n policy-demo delete networkpolicy access-nginx
```

Answer (score 2):

- **PolicyName**: access-nginx
- **Namespace**: default

```sh
kubectl get netpol -n default
NAME           POD-SELECTOR   AGE
access-nginx   run=nginx      60m
```

---

- **Deleting Network Policy**

```sh
kubectl delete networkpolicy access-nginx -n default
```

or

```sh
kubectl delete netpol access-nginx -n default
```

or - using the filename of the resource

```sh
kubectl delete -f access-nginx.yaml
```

---

- **Editing Networking Policy**

By default it will open in yaml format for editing

```sh
kubectl edit netpol access-nginx -n default
```

or - if you prefer in json format

```sh
kubectl edit netpol access-nginx -n default -o json
```

or - using the filename of the resource

```sh
kubectl edit -f access-nginx.yaml
```

Editor preference:

```sh
KUBE_EDITOR='nano' kubectl edit netpol access-nginx -n default
```

or - vim

```sh
KUBE_EDITOR='vim' kubectl edit netpol access-nginx -n default
```

---

In case of `default` namespace it is not required to pass `-n default` as `kubectl` considers `default` namespace as default.